# MultiSelect with ng-dirty ng-valid

Tags: angular, multi-select, primeng

I was using a classic select with the css style bellow

```
select.ng-pristine.ng-invalid {
 border-left: 5px solid $primary-600 !important;
}
select.ng-dirty.ng-valid  {
 border-left: 5px solid $valid !important;
}
select.ng-dirty.ng-invalid  {
 border-left: 5px solid $error !important;
}
```

Now I use the PrimeNG multiselect, but I have same problems with this tag. I didn't know how to use ng-dirty, ng-valid, ng-pristine... with it. I followed the mentioned below class but it doesn't seem to be working

**HTML**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="categories" formControlName="categoriesId" optionLabel="label" [filter]="false" [showToggleAll]="false"
                defaultLabel="-- Caterory --" appendTo="body"></p-multiSelect>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-multiselect {
    padding:8px 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width:100%;
    margin:15px 0;
    border-radius:0;
    z-index: 1;
}
p-multiselect.ng-dirty.ng-valid  {
    border-left: 5px solid $valid !important;
}
```

How can I resize the panel containing items to make at the same size as the select input?
And how can I remove the space that contains x just above items?

[image]

Comment: Can you create a Plunker please ?

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/XkBzC4c1YCjPQeUYECxO/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `ui-multiselect-panel` class :

```
 .ui-multiselect-panel {
     right: 8px;
     left: 8px;
 }
```

And for the cross :

```
.ui-multiselect-header .ui-multiselect-close {
   top: 0.3rem !important;
 }
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eiNXQZ5Kl83zhNw6Pa1f?p=preview)

Comment: thank you ^^ do you have an idea how i can use .ng-dirty and .ng-valid with the multiselect, exactly like select tag in the plunker

Comment: Check my new Plunker, does it answer your request ?

Comment: in the first select there is the color #ccb581 on the side [link](https://image.ibb.co/nPMAqH/Capture.png) and when i choose an item the color changes, but in the second select which is a PrimeNG select, it doesn't work that way

Comment: And now, is it ok ?